Windows Security Event ID 4800 (lock screen) on Win 11 Pro for Workstations
I have a task that is triggered on PC1 whenever the user locks their computer.  This works fine.

I just set it up the same on PC2, but the Event ID 4800 is not logged on this machine when the user locks the screen.  The only difference I can see between the machines is PC2 is "for Workstations".
Is there a way to enable logging of 4800 Event ID?  I tried using 4634 (Logoff), but for some odd reason it made my task fire all the time?  Even though 4634 only showed up in the security log when I locked the computer.
PC1 - Windows 11 Pro, ver 23H2, OS Build 22631.3593
PC2 - Windows 11 Pro for Workstations, ver 23H2, OS build 22631.3593

You have to enable the audit logs you can enable Audit Other Login/Logoff Events by editing the local group policy

Nice, thank you.  With gpedit I navigated Computer Configuration->Windows Settings->Security Settings->Advanced Audit Policy Configuration->System Audit Policies - Local Group Policy Object->Logon/Logoff to find Audit Other Logon/Logoff Events.

@Ramhound if you want to make that an answer I'll accept it.  Thank you

Once I have the ability to create a couple screenshot I will do exactly that.
